# JSP Page opening in Internet Explorer automatically

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer, browser

I have written a JSP page in my application and it is opening automatically in Internet explorer even when I try to access the page in chrome after deploying the application however when I run it locally it runs in chrome. In the page I have used the following javascript files :

https://code.google.com/p/rangy/source/browse/trunk/dev/uncompressed/rangy-core.js?r=640

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/12090631/

Is there anything in javascript that can force a page to open in IE only ? Looked around for solution with no luck. Please help!

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler

Comment: Does not help my application is still opening in Internet Explorer only. Here's the link..try to open it in chrome. http://sigmarichtext.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Before following the deployment process, set your default browser settings in Eclipse:

> Setting the Default Web Browser
>
> The usage of Stardust Portal via the internal Web browser is currently
>   not supported. Set the browser to be used to your default Web browser:
>
> 1. Select Window > Preferences in the main menu
> 2. Select General > Web Browser
> 3. Enable Use external Web browser
> 4. Click Apply

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fdeployment.html